# Ordinary Differential Equations Form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Okay, I just want to understand the basic concept of this ODEs. Let's get to the form of this ODEs, which forms is :
$$F(\ x,\ y,\ y',\ y'',\ \cdots\ ,\ y^{(n)}\ )=0$$It says that the ODE is a differential equation which contains unknown function ( I assume this is $y$ ) WHICH IS has only single variable ( I assume that our $y = f(x)$ ) , and its derivatives ( again I assume this is $y', \ y'',\ \cdots,\ y^{(n)} $ ), am I wrong?

Now, consider an example of ODE of first order $F(\ x,\ y,\ y'\ )=0$, which is : $$(x+1)dx + (y-1)dy=0$$so I assume the form of that equation is $F(\ x+1, \ y-1, \ y')$ am I wrong? Please explain in a clear way, if my assumption is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If can be written $F(x+1,y-1,y') = 0$ if we take $F(x,y,y') = x + yy'$ and it can be written $F(x,y,y') = 0$ if we take $F(x,y,y') = x+1 + (y-1)y'$ and so on and so on. The point here is that the form is just a way to tell us what variables the ODE depend on. For example the $x$ in $F(x,\ldots)$ tells us that there is an explicit $x$-dependence in the ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your equation is 
$$
(x+1)\,dx+(y-1)\,dy=0,
$$
then this can be written as
$$
(x+1)+(y-1)\,y'=0,
$$
and as
$$
F(x,y,y')=0,
$$
where
$$
F(a,b,c)=(a+1)+(b-1)c.
$$

Comment: I got it. thanks for make it clear for me.